# Roblox Studio - Error: stats is not a valid member of Tool

Tags: lua, roblox

!https://gyazo.com/1049793346a4514a33e38f41776c595f <- (Think the problem is in this)

!https://gyazo.com/8dd8e310511801e631c496973938b68d

It comes with an error:
22:49:20.708 - stats is not a valid member of Tool

I can't figure out how to fix the problem, but i'm pretty sure that it is a easy fix, just can't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Roblox Studio - Error that i can't figure out how to fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686527/roblox-studio-error-that-i-cant-figure-out-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 1):

This error sometimes occurs when the engine tries to read the child listed (in this case, `stats`) as a property of the instance instead of a child.

In the `core` LocalScript, trying doing `local stats = tool:FindFirstChild("stats")` instead. This way you can remove any ambiguity about whether `stats` is a property or a child instance for the game.