# Roblox Studio - Error that i can't figure out how to fix

Tags: lua, roblox

!https://gyazo.com/0cb603d9edce56998a8f4428c78f4c41 <- (Think the problem is in this)

!https://gyazo.com/8dd8e310511801e631c496973938b68d

It comes with an error: 09:52:52.637 - Players.asbjornbonde.Backpack.Shovel.core:5: attempt to index local 'stats' (a nil value)

I have tried to find the issue but i really can't. Hope someone can help me with this. Tell me if u need information.

Comment: `stats` on line 4 was set to `nil` likely because `FindFirstChild` didn't find anything.
You need to stop posting screenshots and include the actual code in the text form (the minimal example that demonstrates the issue). In your case since the problem is on line 5, everything below if largely irrelevant to the problem and doesn't need to be posted.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the "core" script and it's on line 5. The error message is telling us that `stats` is a nil value and therefore can't be indexed.

The most likely reason for this is that `stats` on line 4 was set to `nil` because `FindFirstChild` didn't find anything. ~ `@Paul Kulchenko`